# Deep link is not opening the app from facebook post

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have added a deep link support in my app, and it works fine from gmail, messaging apps.

But from facebook, it opens the browser and not the app.

```
 <activity
            android:name="..MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:host="mywebsite.com"/>
                <data android:pathPrefix="/screen1"/>
                <data android:pathPrefix="/screen2"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Do i need to add something additional to make it work on facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to support opening your app from FB is to support FB Applinks - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/

This will give you the option to navigate directly into your app incase it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this issue, while working react native.

any suggestions how this can be fixed.